# ng-show is not updating my view

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I saw many of those issues on the Internet but none of them seems similar to what I did... Or maybe there is the same behavior but I don't know where it happens.

On every site I went it seems that if you do a change of the model somehow  outside angular, the change won't be seen unless you use the "$apply()".

I'm not sure if this is happening in my code and why the view is not updating.

```
$scope.getUsers = function() {
    var promise = $http.get("...");

    promise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.users = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
    promise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      alert("AJAX failed!");
    });
  };

<div ng-show="{{users.length > 0}}">
  <table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-click="setOrder('id')">ID</th>
        <th ng-click="setOrder('login')">Username</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:orderType+orderBy">
        <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
        <td><a href="#/user/{{user.login}}/repos">{{ user.login }}</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ng-show="users.length > 0"
```

The directive expects a boolean angular expression. No need for mustaches.

Comment: I was about to post you beat me by 1 min

Comment: Oh! But what happens when I place the mustaches? Why is not working with them?

Comment: Angular tries to parse it as an expression, but the expression is invalid, which probably causes an error to be logged in the console, and probably a failure to compile the template.

Comment: Well, I didn't get any errors in the console regarding that expression. And the expression works if I have the users array initialized. The same things works on other elements but not in this case, in the case that I make an ajax call and change the users array.

Comment: The expression is not invalid. It's interpolated beforehand and resolves to `"false"`. So basically `ngShow` is watching a constant.